# generate Navigation properties from database with a T4 template

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity, code-generation, t4

I'm trying to find a way of keeping consistency throughout my c# classes and my database objects when creating entity models from the database for entity framework. 
I have decided to take the t4 template route with code first. So every time an apps uses my models I can run the custom tool to get any updates made through SQL management studio and I will have the latest version of POCO's to interacts with the database.

currently I have the classes generated in separate .cs files but cant seem to work out how to represent relationships between the entities. 
An example of what im trying to achieve is in this blog: http://www.haneycodes.net/automatically-generate-pocos-from-db-with-t4/
but, again, the relationships are not shown ?

Comment: What attempts have you made?

Comment: Hi, lloydm....I have dabbled through the  Column type and can see the col.IsForeignKey but Im not sure how to represent this...ive seen a few posts with 
  foreach (var navigationProperty in entityType.NavigationProperties)
and i guess you would use the col.IsForeignKey = true;

but not sure how to get the entityType... Thanks

Comment: Can you be more specific with [sample code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) preferably. Try to break the problem into it's parts. Such as determining a Foreign Key exists. Finding the related table. Creating a ICollection to represent the One to Many relationship. Are you sure you mean [code first](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/migrations-and-deployment-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) and not [database first](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/setting-up-database) ?